# Is there a way to Stealth but allow your allies to target you?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, stealth

In my campaign, I recently acquired Legendary Sneak, meaning I do not need cover nor concealment to retain my Hidden and Undetected conditions when using Stealth. This has some excellent benefits outlined in my [other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/185213/28326) on the matter.

But it does have a significant drawback. Neither Hide nor Sneak allow for you to 'not hide' from allies. This means that if my friendly cleric wants to use their 2-action Heal on me, they must succeed at a Seek action or DC 11 Flat check (assuming I've overcome their Perception DC with my most recent Hide action) among other things my allies may want to do to help me.

> (Hide) ...compares the result to the Perception DC of each creature...
>
> (Sneak) ...compares the result to the Perception DC of each creature you were hidden from or undetected by...

What options, if any, allow me to remain or become Observed by my allies but not all creatures that could perceive me?

Answer (score 4):

## Unrelenting Observation

[Unrelenting Observation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=351) *should* allow you to continue to be noticed by your allies for up to an hour; the spell has a special clause for willing creatures being able to automatically fail the saving throw, so don't even have to worry about willingly failing saves.

> This spell grants perfect sight based on scrying, allowing several willing targets to track the exact movements or position of one creature or object. ... They can perceive the creature or object **perfectly**, allowing them to ignore the concealed or invisible condition, though physical barriers still provide cover. ... If the target to be tracked is willing, the duration is 1 hour.

This will take one of your caster's highest spell slots, which is unfortunate, but you're just that gosh darn sneaky.

### Telepathic Bond, per GM Fiat

A significantly lower level spell (but uncommon), [Telepathic Bond](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=335) *might* work. You theoretically could issue precise enough descriptions to your allies for them to at least know the square you are in, and some GMs may rule that you could be a valid target due to the connection. I don't think I'd rule that way as a GM (I could foresee it causing problems with telepathic creatures, or using [Telepathy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=337) to defeat invisibility), but that's why it's called GM Fiat!